# What is the user interface class of slide up menus?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm wondering if there is a specific UI class that slides up to allow user to make a choice, like the "More" button on the safari or the interface confirming iDevice shut down. Both looks like UIToolBars but they seemed to be rendered so well (the button and the toolbar background) that I am starting to suspect it is a separate class designed specifically for such slide-up choices.

Or are they actually different UIViews with designed background that slides up using animateWithDuration:animations: and the background is a translucent mask? How did apple do it?

Answer (score 3):

UIActionSheet. Here is the code:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"E-Mail",@"SMS", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

i think what you are looking for is an [action sheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mean [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?
 If so, yea its a separate class under `UIView` !

[UIActionSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv4J7.png)